# AddTask() method with Console.ReadLine() called from Main() in C# freezes console

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2017

I come from a sysadmin background, so I'm new to programming and C# specifically.

I have a method AddTask() which is called from a switch statement in the Main(string[] args)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
  foreach (string arg in args)
  {
    switch (arg.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper())
    {
      case "A":
        AddTask();
        break;

      case "C":
        MarkTaskComplete();
        break;

      case "D":
        DeleteLastTask();
        break;

      case "L":
        ListTasks();
        break;

      default:
        ListTasks();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the method:

```
    static void AddTask()
{
  Console.Write("Task to add: ");
  // Console.ReadLine() does not work here, seems to be related to the static method
  // "Task added from variable!" does work on the other hand?
  string task = Console.ReadLine();
  // string task = "Task added from variable!";
  Console.WriteLine(task);
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Tasklist.txt", append: true);
  tw.WriteLine(task);
  tw.Close();
}
```

The app compiles without errors, but when I run it with the "A"-switch it just freezes the console, and I eventually have to close it with Ctrl-C. It does not even display the "Task to add: " text from the first Console.Write().

If I don't take user input but use the commented out line:

```
string task = "Task added from variable!";
```

It also works as intended.

Initially I had the AddTask() functionality directly in the Main() method where it worked as intended. But I wanted to separate out functionality in discrete methods for better readability.

As far as I can tell the problem is with the static void part of the method, but I'm not sure exactly how/what/why. As I mentioned I'm just starting out with this.

I tested making the method public static void, but that did not have any effect. It still compiles without error, and it still locks up the console when trying to run with the "A"-switch.

As you can tell from the switch-statement I have a number of other methods (some of which were part of the Main() method as well) and they all function as intended. But none of them take user input.

---

Update: I wrote it freezes the console but I'd been running it in Powershell on Windows 10, which still freezes when running it with the "A"-switch. And it worked in Powershell when the same code was included directly in the Main() method.

Running it in CMD on the same machine it runs as intended.

---

Update once more: I should have been more diligent in my testing... The issue is apparently only with Powershell ISE.

When running in CMD and the basic Powershell Console it works as intended.

When running from the Powershell ISE (as myself) the screen flashes briefly as if a separate console window is opened and closed instantly and then PS ISE just locks up/freezes and no typing or pressing of `ENTER` will return me to the prompt. When running ISE elevated almost the same thing happens except I see no screen flash.

Comment: Hmm...when it freezes the console, did you try typing anything in your keyboard (with the console application focused)? Like pressing `ENTER`...

Comment: I've added the following update to my question: 
Update: I wrote it freezes the console but I'd been running it in Powershell on Windows 10, which still freezes when running it with the "A"-switch. And it worked in Powershell when the same code was included directly in the Main() method.

Running it in CMD on the same machine it runs as intended.

And yes, I tried typing and pressing `ENTER` and nothing shows in Powershell and nothing is added to the Tasklist.txt file.